# Automated way of moving variable string to the top

Tags: automation

I have thousands of HTML files each having a string that starts with same characters but ends differently. I want an automated method to move that string of each file to the top line. Here is the layout of the problem:

```
001.html source:
lksjds
65:99430
lksdmls

002.html source:
kjsndsk
65:09i

003.html source:
knknknkn
sderokfeokfr
65:3498u
lksdmlsre
```

Now, I want them to look like this [finding 65:* with regular expression and then shifting it to the top]:

```
001.html source:
65:99430
lksjds
lksdmls

002.html source:
65:09i
kjsndsk

003.html source:
65:3498u
knknknkn
sderokfeokfr
lksdmlsre
```

Comment: There are many ways to do it. What technologies are you comfortable with -- so we can suggest viable solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `grep` in a bash shell on Unix with file 003.html:

```
   FILE="003.html"
   PATTERN="^65:.*"
   TEMP_FILE="${RANDOM}"

   grep --color=never "${PATTERN}" "${FILE}" > "${TEMP_FILE}"
   grep -v "${PATTERN}" "${FILE}" >> "$TEMP_FILE"
   mv "${TEMP_FILE}" "${FILE}"
```

This can be one-lined and placed inside a `for` loop iterating on each Html file, like it:

```
   for FILE in $(ls *.html); do PATTERN="^65:.*"; TEMP_FILE="${RANDOM}"; grep --color=never "${PATTERN}" "${FILE}" > "${TEMP_FILE}" ; grep -v "${PATTERN}" "${FILE}" >> "$TEMP_FILE"; mv "${TEMP_FILE}" "${FILE}"; done
```

Comment: Can it be done on Windows since I don't have unix/linux/cygwin? Thank you!